# Product of cotangents of angles in arithmetic progression

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that for every integer $m>1$
>   $$\cot\frac{\pi}{2m}\cot\frac{2\pi}{2m}\cot\frac{3\pi}{2m}\cdots\cot\frac{(m-1)\pi}{2m}=1$$

I am not sure how to start this problem. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/24/01/0001/

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that for $0<x<\pi/2$, 
$$\cot(x)\cot(\pi/2-x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\cdot \frac{\cos(\pi/2-x)}{\sin(\pi/2-x)}=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\cdot \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} =1.$$
Moreover for $k=1,\dots, m-1$,
$$\frac{k\pi}{2m}+\frac{(m-k)\pi}{2m}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Oh right. Thanks Robert Z

Comment: @Amrit Cassim Well done. If you are new here please take a few minutes for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour